# Layer-list with bitmaps doesn't care about size

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-drawable, layer-list

I'm using a layer-list with bitmaps like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:height="200dp" android:width="200dp" android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/intro1" />
</item>
<item android:height="200dp" android:width="200dp" android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/intro2" />
</item>
<item android:height="200dp" android:width="200dp" android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/intro3" />
</item>
```

But when adding this resource as background for my viewPager, the background is stretched to fit the whole view.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/intro_layer_drawable"
        />
```

So it seems like the sizes added for each item is neglected on devices with API < 23.

The problem is that I need to set the backgrounds like this, since I modify each page heavily with pageTransformer already.

Any suggestions how to force old phones to also get the proper sizes?

Comment: shouldn't your view pager width and height needs to be wrapping its content instead of matching its parent?

Comment: Trying to use wrap_content instead, but with the same result as before. :(